# Taking contents from separate HTML templates and using them on another

Tags: html, css, templates, merge

Looking for some tips. I have two HTML templates that I am using. The first is my standard one used across the board, the second has a portfolio page with elements in which I am wanting to use in my standard template. I want to keep the header and footer the same, but have content from the second template. How can this be achievable?

I have taken the root folder from the second template, and made a copy, and pasted it within the root folder of my standard template. I copied the html to link to the stylesheets from the second template, and pasted it in to the standard template, but the content still isn't showing. Here's what I have:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Page Title -->
    <title>Not Found - Alioth</title>
    <!--/ Page Title -->

    <meta name="author" content="Pe Themes">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative Portfolio & Agency Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="portfolio, agency, personal, creative">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
     <!-- Portfolio Template Stylesheets (what you can see is I linked them within the template folder I pasted in to the main root folder) -->
    <link href="Portfolio/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/includes/fontawesome/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/js/locomotive-scroll/locomotive-scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/js/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/js/flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/js/swiper/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/js/plyr/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="Portfolio/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <!-- End Stylesheets -->

<!-- Standard Template Stylesheets --!>
    <link href="css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <!--/ Favicons -->
```

So far, nothing has been thrown off. But my content simply isn't showing. Any tips??

Here is the code I'm trying to migrate over to the standard template.

```
  <!-- Begin Main -->
        <div class="portfolio pixi" data-displacement-image="portfolio/images/nm-04.jpg">
            <div class="projects-container">
                <div class="wrapper">

                    <article data-year="2021">

                        <a href="project-sample-1.html">Audi RS7</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-1.html">Audi RS7</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-1-6.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-1-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-1-4.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-1.html">
                                <span>Audi RS7</span>
                                <img src="images/project-1-3.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2021">

                        <a href="project-sample-4.html">Zero Motors</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-4.html">Zero Motors</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-4-2.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-4-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-4-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-4-4.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-4.html">
                                <span>Zero Motors</span>
                                <img src="images/project-4-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2021">

                        <a href="project-sample-2.html">Swiss Alps</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-2.html">Swiss Alps</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-3-2.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-3-4.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-3-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-3-5.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-3-6.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-2.html">
                                <span>Swiss Alps</span>
                                <img src="images/project-3-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2020">

                        <a href="project-sample-5.html">Wildlings</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-5.html">Wildlings</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-5-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-5-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-5-4.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-5-5.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-5-6.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-5.html">
                                <span>Wildlings</span>
                                <img src="images/project-5-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>
                    
                    <article data-year="2020">

                        <a href="project-sample-6.html">Dubai</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-6.html">Dubai</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-6-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-6-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-6-5.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-6-6.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-6.html">
                                <span>Dubai</span>
                                <img src="images/project-6-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2021">

                        <a href="project-sample-3.html">Audi A3</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-3.html">Audi A3</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-2-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-2-2.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/project-2-7.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-3.html">
                                <span>Audi A3</span>
                                <img src="images/project-2-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2020">

                        <a href="project-sample-3.html">New York</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-3.html">New York</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/project-6-13.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/strips-9.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/full-10.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-3.html">
                                <span>New York</span>
                                <img src="images/full-10.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2019">

                        <a href="project-sample-6.html">Last Summer</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-6.html">Last Summer</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/full-11.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/grid-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/full-3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-6.html">
                                <span>Last Summer</span>
                                <img src="images/full-11.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                    <article data-year="2021">

                        <a href="project-sample-1.html">Iceland</a>

                        <div class="image-text">
                            <a href="project-sample-1.html">Iceland</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="images">
                            <img src="images/full-8.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/full-6.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/grid-11.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mobile">
                            <a href="project-sample-1.html">
                                <span>Iceland</span>
                                <img src="images/full-8.jpg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End Main -->
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't provide your full example because there's no actual content in there, so the result of no content showing would be expected?

Comment: Of course. This was simply my stylesheets I was showing. I went ahead and added it! I wanted to know if this was the correct process and I can simply now copy and paste the html from the Portfolio template or is there another "migration" step I am missing?

Comment: Technically you would just need the css classes that apply to classes used in the html you're adding. Careful though if you're not familiar with CSS and you're just stacking more potentially large style sheets on one another, it just greatly increases for the chances of classes/selector name collisions and adds a lot of bloat that can effect performance forcing visitors to download a bunch of redundant (and unminified) css they don't even need.

Comment: One method I tried was simply change the header of the second template to the header of the first, then it would duplicate. But this doesn't seem to work well either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I think a better option is to copy the required code from the second template and treat it like new in the fresh template, that way, you can apply your CSS stylings, without referring to the previous template.

it should be a standalone template without referring to the first

Comment: So I have two templates. One is the main template. The other has a portfolio page I want to use on the main template. But obviously, copying the pasting the direct html code results in standard text, since the original stylesheets are not linked.